# Excel: Search Project List, Return Number of Hours Per Project

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns:

- **Column A** which contains Project Names
- **Column B** which contains hours.

Information in `Column A` is duplicated, for example: `Project X` may appear 7 times.

How can I come up with the total number of hours for each project?

Comment: This is precisely what the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) is designed to do.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.